# Riverpod on updating a list

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm pretty new to Flutter, and I'm trying out Riverpod to manage my app's state. I'm trying to figure out how to update a list I got from an API.

Right now, I've got this class called Product that stores all the info about my products. Then there's another class called ProductAPI, which has a function called getProductList.

I've got two screens: ProductScreen and ProductDetailScreen. In ProductScreen, I fetch the getProductList API whenever I go there, using FutureProvider. It then shows a list of products in a ListView with ListTile.

When I pick a product, it takes me to the ProductDetailScreen. Inside that screen, there's a text field where I can edit the product name only.

I don't need to call an API to update the product because I have a button to save everything in ProductScreen once I've made all the updates.

But here's the problem: After I update the product name, how do I also update the list in the ProductScreen? Do i need a StateProvider to store the list after I fetch the list?

Comment: Two basic strategies: source of truth is remote, so you roundtrip all data to server and reload it; or source of truth is locally optimistic, so you use local cache as a write-through.  Depends mostly on whether you expect concurrent updates, which forces a remote source of truth.

Comment: If you are using a FutureProvider, you can invalidate that provider like ref.invalidate(yourFutureProvider) after the title change is complete.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand from your question, the problem is that when you edit a product's name in ProuductDeatailScreen then press a button to save it (and probably call a patch method from your API to update it in db) and get back to ProductsListScreen, the name of the updated product is not updated.

I suggest you to use "watch" method from riverpod for your productsFutureProvider in build method of ProductsListScreen.

If it does not solve it please be comfortable and inform me.